# Passing arbitrary information for a functional parameter to use

Tags: c++, polymorphism

In C++:

I have an object I'll call Foo.

Foo performs statistical operations on a supplied data set. The first step of the process involves a fitting function, and a functional parameter can be supplied so that the user can specify the type of model being used.

The problem is that I now have a situation where the function parameter needs to have access to data that does not exist in Foo but rather in the object that is using Foo, which I will call Bar.

So Bar calls Foo to have Foo operate on Bar's data. Bar has a specific function it wants to use as the functional parameter but this function requires information specific to Bar.

- I don't want to pass Bar because if I code Foo up to receive Bar, then every time I have a new object that needs additional info passed to Foo, I will have to adjust the Foo class to accept that object.
- I don't want to modify the functional parameter input in Foo because then I'll have to modify the functional parameter input for every new usage case as well.

I considered using a base class I'll call StandardFunc. Then, via virtual methods, Bar could create an object called ModifiedFunc that derives from StandardFunc. It could override the StandardFunc's function and also supply the additional info as class parameters. This doesn't work either because to avoid slicing I have to type-cast ModifiedFunc to StandardFunc. This means that inside Foo I have to change the type-cast line for every new object name.

Can someone please point me in the right direction for how I can allow users to pass either a functional parameter alongside arbitrary parameters the function requires without having to recode the Foo class for every different usage case? I'm really stuck on this.

EDIT: pseudo code example:

```
class Foo
{
    void processHandler(function)
    void process();
    void process(function);
    void theUsualFunction(vector); //the default function used by process
    vector vec;
};
void Foo::process()
{
    processHandler(theUsualFunction);
}
void Foo::process(function f)
{
    processHandler(f)
}
void Foo::processHandler(function f)
{
    f(vec)
    //do other stuff to vec
}
void Foo::theUsualFunction(vector v)
{
    //default vec processor
}

class Bar
{
    int x;
    int y;
    vector vec;
    void theModifiedFunction(vector);
    void callFooToProcess();
};
void Bar::theModifiedFunction(vector v)
{
    //process v, but in a way that requires x and y
}
void Bar::callFooToProcess()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.setVector(vec);
    process(theModifiedFunction); 
}
```

So this code is kind of an example of what I want to achieve, but it doesn't work as written. The reason is because I have no way of getting Bar::x and Bar::y to the function Foo::processHandler(function) without modifying the arguments for Foo::processHandler, and I don't want to do that because then every new class like Bar and every new theModifiedFunction that requires different data will require me to rewrite the arguments for processHandler.

Comment: This seems like an ideal use case for lambdas, which are relatively new in C++ but have been around in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

> This doesn't work either because to avoid slicing I have to type-cast ModifiedFunc to StandardFunc.

Slicing only occurs if you pass the argument by value. You should pass it as a pointer, that's how polymorphism is supposed to work.

Also, you can keep passing the argument by value if you make your class a template:

```
template<class Func>
class Foo {
    void doStuff(Func func) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Keep in mind though, that in this case `Func` has to be known at compile-time.

Comment: Well if I use pointers to take advantage of polymorphism, then I end up with a StandardFunc class with stFunc as a member of Foo. Then I allow the user to call setFunc and pass a ModifiedFunc object (a subclass of StandardFunc). Then I have to typecast my Foo.stFunc as a ModifiedFunc or else the additional data isn't available. This requires recoding the typecast line in Foo if someone supplies a class called "ModifiedFunction" instead of "ModifiedFunc",

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're trying to achieve. Consider expanding your question with sample code pls.

Answer (score 0):

Although there may be other ways of handling this situation, I would suggest considering to have Bar contain Foo. This is called a `has-a` relationship [[wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a). The advantage of this is that you can use Foo as-is without modifying anything within Foo, as well as Bar need not pass around its private data. Hope the following code snippet would help you to understand the concept.

```
public class Bar
{
    private Foo myFoo;
    private int myInfo;

    void a()
    {
        myFoo.doStuff(myInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could do this but I would really like a solution to the problem that is self-contained within Foo.